# strlen segfaults on 2d dynamic array of strings

Tags: multidimensional-array, dynamic, segmentation-fault, c-strings, strlen

Why do I get a segfault when I try to print the strlen of a string, which is part of an array of strings? I can print each string - the printf works perfectly. But why does the strlen cause a segfault?

The below program first takes an input n, which is the number of strings I want to dynamically allocate. Then I allocate space for 32 bytes for each string

```
int main() {
    int i;
    int n;
    char **nums;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("n = %d\n", n);
    nums = malloc(sizeof(char *) * n);
    printf("allocated nums\n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        nums[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 32);
        memset(nums[i], '\0', sizeof(char) * 32);
    }
    for(i=0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%s", &nums[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        // THIS PRINTS FINE
        printf("string = %s\n", &nums[i]);
        // SEGFAULT HERE IMMEDIATELY
        printf("length = %d\n", strlen(nums[i]));
    }
```

Here is the console output. As a test, I entered in n=3, followed by the numbers 45, 46, and 47:

```
3
n = 3
allocated nums
45
46
47
string = 45
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Additionally, I get a segfault when I try to access an individual character in each string. Again, the first printf in outer for loop prints the string, then I get a segfault accessing nums[i][k]:

```
    int i, k=0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("Printiiing: %s\n", &nums[i]);
        // WHY DOES THIS SEGFAULT???
        //printf("first char = %c\n", nums[i][0]);
        while(k<32 && nums[i][k] != '\0') {
            // THIS CAUSES A SEG FAULT
            printf("char = %c", (nums[i])[k]);
            k++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fine:

```
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        nums[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 32);
        memset(nums[i], '\0', sizeof(char) * 32);
    }
```

After this loop, each `nums[i]` is a pointer to 32-byte buffer.

But this corrupts (overwrites) all the pointers, instead of reading strings into the allocated buffers:

```
    for(i=0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%s", &nums[i]);
    }
```

To fix the bug, use: `scanf("%s", nums[i]);`.

Answer (score 0):

There is the difference pointer between the `&nums[i]` and `nums[i]` address. You can check with the `strlen((const char*)(&nums[i]))` for get length.
The explanation of @Employee of Russia is exactly for reason.